# SMTP server Configuration

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have Windows XP and configured SMTP server in my *IIS*. Specified `AllUnAssigned` in *IP* address of general tab and specified `127.0.0.1` in connection under *Access* tab.

Now I tried sending mails using my local SMTP server using the following code,

```
MailMessage amessage = new MailMessage();
amessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
amessage.From = new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com");
amessage.Subject = "TestMail";
amessage.Body = "This is a testmail";
SmtpClient clienta = new SmtpClient("localhost");
clienta.Timeout = 500;
clienta.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
try
{
    clienta.Send(amessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

   Console.WriteLine(ex);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't get any error in executing the above code but no mails were sent/received. When I checked in the Inetpub I find the below file:

> From: postmaster@munged 
>   To: yyy@gmail.com 
>   Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2011 11:07:22 +0530
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/report;
>   report-type=delivery-status;
>     boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01CC03D260FE2C6C00000003munged?xxx"
>   Message-ID:
>   
>   Subject: Delivery Status Notification
>   (Failure)
>
> This is a MIME-formatted message.
>   Portions of this message may be
>   unreadable without a MIME-capable mail
>   program.
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC03D260FE2C6C00000003munged?munged
>   Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7
>
> This is an automatically generated
>   Delivery Status Notification.
>
> Delivery to the following recipients
>   failed.
>
> ```
>    xxx@gmail.com
> ```
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC03D260FE2C6C00000003munged?munged
>   Content-Type: message/delivery-status
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns;munged
>   Received-From-MTA: dns;munged
>   Arrival-Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2011
>   11:07:16 +0530
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;xxx@gmail.com
>   Action: failed Status: 5.0.0
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-5.7.1
>   [122.178.191.78] The IP you're using
>   to send mail is not authorized to
>   550-5.7.1 send email directly to our
>   servers. Please use the SMTP relay at
>   your 550-5.7.1 service provider
>   instead. Learn more at
>   550 5.7.1
>   http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336
>   m9si19863225wfl.114
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC03D260FE2C6C00000003munged?munged
>   Content-Type: message/rfc822
>
> Received: from munged
>   ([127.0.0.1]) by munged with
>   Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.2600.2180);
>   Tue, 26 Apr 2011 11:07:16 +0530
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 From: yyy@gmail.com
>   To: xxx@gmail.com Date: 26 Apr 2011
>   11:07:16 +0530 Subject: TestMail
>   Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=us-ascii
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   quoted-printable Return-Path:
>   munged@gmail.com Message-ID:
>   
>   X-OriginalArrivalTime: 26 Apr 2011
>   05:37:16.0515 (UTC)
>   FILETIME=[009D2330:01CC03D4]
>
> This is a testmail
>
> --9B095B5ADSN=_01CC03D260FE2C6C00000003munged?munged--

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: on error message it says "The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
550 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 m9si19863225wfl.114" so you should search answer on gmail side..your code seems post item to mail server but it did not send over....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the important part of the error message:

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-5.7.1 [122.178.191.78] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead.

To solve this, you'll need to setup an SMTP relay to **send to your ISP's email servers**. They'll send to Google for you.

For clarity:

- This is NOT an application/code/C# problem, but an IIS problem.
- Google will NOT accept SMTP connections from random nodes on the internet. That means: YOUR Windows XP SMTP server will not have direct sending ability.
- You MUST send to a known good whitelisted SMTP host.
- Your best option is to configure IIS to act as a relay to a known good SMTP server.
- Your best bet for a known good SMTP server is your ISP's. This is likely `smtp.yourISP.com`.
- This [tutorial's](http://spinplate.com/2008/07/set-up-local-smtp-service-to-relay-e-mail-to-a-mail-server/) Steps 2 & 3 will help you achieve this. Your 'smart host' will be your ISP's SMTP server DNS name or IP address.

Comment: I have added both my IP address and 127.0.0.1 in Relay Part in SMTP server.But still couldnt get it. Can u please help me, what to be done? Thanks

Comment: *Your ISP's email servers* will be the ones allowed to send to Google, not any/all SMTP servers out on the internet. Have your IIS SMTP forward to your ISP email servers. i.e. fwd to `smtp.yourISP.com`

Comment: Am sorry for bugging u again..Can u please tel me what to be done since am new to SMTP configuration. I couldnt get wat u said in the previous comment. Is anything more to be done under Relay section. please.

Comment: I have done all the above steps u mentioned but now my error message is Diagnostic-Code: smtp;530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q10sm3263359pbk.39

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to send emails through gmail from your PC, you should encrypt your data with SSL. You have to options here:

- use specific asp functions
- use a software like stunnel (it is not so difficult to configure)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer helps the problem of sending mail to Google? What does this actually mean: 'use specific asp functions'?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using one of the following two ways

Option 1. Change '127.0.01' to 'localhost' in connection under Access tab.

Option 2. Change the code used to connect using '127.0.01' instead of localhost.

```
    SmtpClient clienta = new SmtpClient("127.0.01");
```

Comment: Tried the options with out success